# Conditionally showing Back Button in NavigationExperimental NavigationCardStack

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the `NavigationCardStack` from `NavigationExperimental` in my RN app.

Is there a way to conditionally show the back button on the navbar?

I found the following statement in the documentation that seems to insist their isn't, but it just doesn't make sense that something this simple couldn't be done.

```
  The CardStack example loses out on some of the modal functionality,      
  such as disabling the back gesture responder, and "closing" the modal 
  results in a horizontal transition instead of a vertical. These things 
  cannot be overriden due to how the CardStack component is currently written.
```

My implementation looks like the following:

```
render() {

  let backAction = ()=> this.props.dispatch(navigatePop());
  let onNavigate = (action)=> backAction();
  return (
    <View style={ styles.container }>
          <NavigationCardStack
            navigationState={this.props.navigationState}
            onNavigateBack={backAction}
            onNavigate={onNavigate}
            style={styles.container}
            direction='horizontal'
            renderOverlay={props => this._renderHeader(props,backAction)}
            renderScene={this._renderScene}
          />
    </View>
  );
}

_renderScene({scene}) {
  const { navigationState } = scene
  switch(navigationState.key) {
  case 'Login':
    return <Login />
  case 'Profile':
    return <Profile />
  case 'Home':
    return <MainNavigation />
  case 'Create Group':
    return <CreateGroup />
  }
}

_renderHeader(props,backAction){
  return (
      <NavigationHeader
      {...props}
      onNavigateBack={backAction}
      renderTitleComponent={props => this._renderHeaderTitle(props)}
    />
  )
}

_renderHeaderTitle(props){
  let title = props.scene.navigationState.title
  if(title == 'Home'){
    title = this._renderSubTitle(props);
  }
  return <NavigationHeader.Title>{title}</NavigationHeader.Title>
}

_renderSubTitle(props){
    var navigation = this.props.mainNavigation;
        var tab = navigation.children[navigation.index];
        return tab.title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
_renderLeft(props){
  // Insert code to render back button.
  // props.scene.index and props.scene.route.key will help you identify the navigation route you're currently in.
}
_renderHeader(props, backAction){
  return (
    <NavigationHeader
      {..props}
      onNavigateBack={backAction}
      renderTitleComponent={props => this._renderHeaderTitle(props)}
      // new code below
      renderLeftComponent={props => this._renderLeft(props)}
    />
  )
}
```